# Setting initial position of NSWindow only works the first time

Tags: macos, nswindow

I'm trying to set my NSWindow to be in the center of the screen, but I'm noticing that when I quit and reopen the app, it takes the position that the window was in when the app closed.  Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you selected "Restorable" window behaviour then it's the correct behaviour. 
[image: Restorable]

You can disable this by behaviour by unchecking restorable and also leave your autosave name empty.

Your application saves the state into "~/Library/Saved Application State/com.identifier.appName.savedState" folder and loads on launch 
 [image: Saved app state]

Also one hidden hack to help:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@NO forKey:@"NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows"];
}
```